# Styling Joomla custom fields

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, custom-field

0

i have created some custom fields in Joomla and created an over-ride:

/components/com_fields/layouts/field/render.php to /templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/layouts/com_fields/field/MY_OVERRIDE.ph

Currently the fields show as such:

```
Field 1 
Field 2 
Field 3
```

I would like to display them as:

```
Field 1 Field 2 Field 3
```

I am OK styling them with css but my php skills are lacking.

This seems to be part of code that outputs it and i have tried putting tables in but no luck. Also don't understand why there is not an echo for each field.

Thanks for any help!

```
<?php if ($showLabel == 1) : ?>
    <span class="field-label <?php echo $labelClass; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($label, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, 'UTF-8'); ?>: </span>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($prefix) : ?>
    <span class="field-prefix"><?php echo htmlentities($prefix, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, 'UTF-8'); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<span class="field-value <?php echo $valueClass; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></span>
<?php if ($suffix) : ?>
    <span class="field-suffix"><?php echo htmlentities($suffix, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, 'UTF-8'); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom fields are rendered inside an **ul.fields-container** as **li.filed-entry**.
So, why don't convert the **ul** into a flexy div and use flex-flow to define the layout of the fileds?

Btw there are 2 files into com_fields/layout

- field/render.php, the one you overriddend, that controls the single custom field
- fields/render.php that controls the list.

Overriding the **fileds**/render.php you can change how the container of the single custom items is displayed.

Comment: Thank you Davide. That has clarified a few things. Where do I find the  ul.fields-container and li.filed-entry code?

Comment: The list is located in the components/com_fields/layouts/fields/render.php
The item is in the field/render.php (same path)
To override them use the override feature of your template... so in Admin, select System, then template -> site template, then Create Ovverride -> layout -> com_fields